# How to change color for selected tabs in tablayout?

Tags: android

Suppose i want set color for tabs in tablayout based on following conditions
1. Un selected tabs = blue
2. Current tab = green
3. Selected tabs = red

Here am using following code for changing color for unselected and current tab

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- UNSELECTED TAB STATE -->
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <!-- Bottom indicator color for the UNSELECTED tab state -->
            <item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke android:color="#65acee" android:width="2dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <!-- Current TAB STATE -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <!-- Tab background color for the SELECTED tab state -->
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#cef9ff"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <!-- Bottom indicator color for the SELECTED tab state -->
            <item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke android:color="#5beea6" android:width="2dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

but failed to retain previously selected tab

refer this [image]

car reading is selected state
capture photo and signature are unselected state

am using view pager...after moving from car reading to capture photo...car reading background should be in green color

Comment: 2. Current tab = green 3. Selected tabs = red whts the difference?

Comment: suppose am in tab position 2 then tab2 is current tab

Comment: if you are in tab position 2,then it must be selected tab right?

Comment: suppose there are 5 tabs in tablyout. starting position at 0. and moving from 0 to 2 then tab0 ,tab1 and tab2 is selected

Comment: then starting position is selected

Comment: please upload expected output

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use a selector for this. Because once you select a new tab Android will mark the old tab as unselected. What you would need to do is create a TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() then in the onTabSelected and onTabUnselected methods you can get the customView of the tab and set the background color on it.

Note: This requires you set a custom view for your tab. Otherwise you can't programatically change the background color. The only way to change background colors with the default tab layout is through styles which won't work in your case.

Comment: Might be easier, and better, to change the icon (or iconLevel if possible) to mark tab as read.

Comment: Yea I would agree changing the icon is far easier than trying to change the background color.